# Thymeleaf exception Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Edited with @Crafalo suggestion

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/dict/adder}" th:object="${dictionary}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Typ slownika:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{dict}"  id="dropType">
                    <option value="0" th:text="select operator" ></option>
                    <option th:each="dict : ${dictList}" th:value="${dict.id}"
                            th:text="${dict.description}">Cos</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Controller

```
  List<Dictionary> dictList = dictService.findAllDictionaries();
        model.addAttribute("dictionary", new Dictionary());
        model.addAttribute("dictList", dictList);



Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dict' available as request attribute
```

In select/option i want have a parnet Dictionary in this form i need create a child Dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is in your th:field

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="${dictionary.description}"  id="dropType">
```

Should be

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{id}"  id="dropType">
```

And in some place have the form

```
<form th:object="${dictionary}">
```

UPDATE:

You also need to send to the view the "dictionary" object in the model

```
model.addAttribute("dictionary", new Dictionary());
```

Another mistake is in your first option tag

```
th:text="select operator"
```

When you use the th: prefix is because you want to read some value from the controller, but if in this case you just want to write some fixed text, use a normal option tag, change it for:

```
<option value="0">select operator</option>
```

Comment: I edited my main post. I have <form th:object="${dictionary}">, because all form is the post method but i need one element of form create by model attribute

Comment: @jan345 be sure you are sending the object "dictionary" in the model, and  remove the preffix "dictionary" from the select field. Check my response

Comment: I change name from dictionary to dict in select /option , a added 
model.addAttribute("dictionary", new Dictionary()); , but i now have 
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'dict' available as request attribute

Comment: No you confused. First add attribute "dictionary" to the model, in the form tag add th:object="${dictionary}", in your select ONLY leave this th:field="*{description}" or the id of your dictionary, i think should be some id not a string

Comment: Uppss, i'm confused can you tell me more with this edited code?

Comment: @jan345 in the field of you select, you need to say the ID attribute. You need to say thymeleaf which value have to store in that field, and you are using a list of dictionaries, where you use the ID as value, so should be th:field="*{id}"

Comment: I change it but i get Could not parse as expression: "select operator"

Comment: @jan345 you had another mistake in the option declaration, i added how to fix in my response :)

Comment: Thank you, one more question i get Bean property 'dict' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:, i use lombok library , this is cause of problem?

Comment: @jan345 no, just be sure you have all getters/setters for the Dictionary class. Could you also validate my response? so could be useful for others users? Thanks!